# Had an unmarried Jewish woman ever owned a male slave, whom she acquired or asked to become her husband?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, history, marriage, slave-serve-eved-avadim

Had an unmarried Jewish woman ever owned a male slave, whom she acquired or asked to become her husband?

Was there ever any occurrence in the Tanach, Gemara, Mishna, Halacha, Aggadot, Midrashim, etc. of a single Jewish woman or a widowed Jewish woman who owned a male slave, whom she acquired or asked to become her husband?

In which circumstance could such a union be halachically permitted?

I ask this out of curiosity and for personal study. If I could have simply searched this for myself (like go to such and such search engine at such and such, where it is hooked up to all Jewish sources), then please teach me how and where I could have searched this. Thanks.

Comment: this is prohibited

Comment: @kouty why?  She could free him first.  (Also can a woman own an eved ivri?  Then she wouldn't have to free him.)

Comment: this is in mishna. a woman,cannot buy male slaves

Comment: @kouty I understand that a woman can not buy male slaves, but where in the Mishna or Halacha or Gemara does it say she can not inherit a male slave?

Comment: @kouty - please remind me where this Mishna is.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I don't know if the following is what other people might be thinking of,"הָאִשָּׁה קוֹנָה שְׁפָחוֹת אֲבָל אֵינָהּ קוֹנָה עֲבָדִים, אֲפִלּוּ קְטַנִּים, מִפָּנָי הַחֲשָׁד". https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.267.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Thanks, but that's in Shulchan Aruch - based on a Gemara in Bava Metzia 71. But @kouty claimed it was a Mishna - and I was wondering if my memory has gone faulty. (As to your question, the "kosher" scenario could be that she inherits a slave and then frees him to marry him. Fascinating question.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann I understand, from this passage, that a woman can not buy male slaves, but where in the Mishna or Halacha or Gemara does it say she can not inherit a male slave? If she does, where does it say, when she must get rid of them.

Comment: @ninamag - that's what I'm trying to say; I agree with you. I think you have a great question!

Comment: You start by asking if it ever happened. I think you should reword it so as to speak about the halacha rather than the history.

Comment: @sabbahillel by deleting the first question?

Comment: @DannySchoemann since you thought that I "have a great question", can you help me re-word this, in order to satisfy sabbahillel's suggestion?

Comment: @Danny I was wrong, memory...

Comment: Change the question from if it ever happened to what are the halachic discussions involving a Jewish woman and an eved cna'ani and kiddushin. I think that there is a discussion (as an example) in the gemara if an eved says *you are mekadesh to me once I become free* or a nonJew say *you are mekadesh to me once I complete becoming a ger*

Comment: What does "at least" mean?

Comment: @msh210 in this case this phrase "at least" can be safely ignored, and the question remains the same. I only meant to use it, in the sense of, of course, she can own a female slave, a donkey, a bull, etc, but my question called for her to specifically own a male slave.

Comment: @DannySchoemann According to Yevamoth 67a, a woman, even a Koheneth, can inherit and, therefore, own male slaves.

Comment: @ninamag  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84821/5120

Comment: Can someone please explain to me how the application of Halacha is off-topic as Jews not Judaism?

Answer (score 5):

Example in Tanach of woman marrying a slave:[Divrei Hayomim 1, 2,35]-

> וַיִּתֵּן שֵׁשָׁן אֶת-בִּתּוֹ לְיַרְחָע עַבְדּוֹ, לְאִשָּׁה; וַתֵּלֶד לוֹ, אֶת-עַתָּי - So Sheshan gave his daughter to Jarha his servant to wife; and she bore him Attai.

Rashi explains There were 14 generations till Yishmael ben Netania who killed Gedalia ben Achikam to show that there are bad genes from bad yichus (see [Jeremiah 41:2][2]-3) and meforshim.פרש"י ולששן עבד מצרי ירחע ויתן את בתו לירחע המצרי עבדו ומספר בגנותן כלומר לא היו ראויין למלכות ויצא ממנו ישמעאל בן נתניה בן אלישמע שהרג גדליה בן אחיקם ( ירמיה מ"א
She must have married an *eved meshuchrar*(freed slave who is Jewish) as marriage won't work to an *eved canaani* as evident in Kidushin 66b.

The mishna  Yevamoth 67a says that a woman can own inherited male slaves:

> מתני' בת ישראל שניסת לכהן ומת והניחה מעוברת לא יאכלו עבדיה בתרומה מפני חלקו של עובר
> an Israelite daughter who married a cohen and he died and left her pregnant, her slaves may not eat teruma because of the portion of ownership of the fetus

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64396/discussion-on-answer-by-user15464-had-an-unmarried-jewish-woman-ever-owned-at-le).

Answer (score 1):

Halachically, [*Kiddushin chapter 3 Mishnah 5*](http://learn.conservativeyeshiva.org/kiddushin-chapter-three-mishnah-five/) says that the eved must be freed first before any marriage can take place. Once he has been freed, he is like any other Jew and it would not be any different from any other marriage. Any kiddushin done while he is an eved is invalid.

> הַמְקַדֵּשׁ אֶת הָאִשָּׁה וְאָמַר, כְּסָבוּר הָיִיתִי שֶׁהִיא כֹהֶנֶת
>   וַהֲרֵי הִיא לְוִיָּה, לְוִיָּה וַהֲרֵי הִיא כֹהֶנֶת, עֲנִיָּה וַהֲרֵי
>   הִיא עֲשִׁירָה, עֲשִׁירָה וַהֲרֵי הִיא עֲנִיָּה, הֲרֵי זוֹ
>   מְקֻדֶּשֶׁת, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁלֹּא הִטְעַתּוּ. הָאוֹמֵר לְאִשָּׁה, הֲרֵי
>   אַתְּ מְקֻדֶּשֶׁת לִי לְאַחַר שֶׁאֶתְגַּיֵּר אוֹ לְאַחַר
>   שֶׁתִּתְגַּיְּרִי, לְאַחַר שֶׁאֶשְׁתַּחְרֵר אוֹ לְאַחַר
>   שֶׁתִּשְׁתַּחְרְרִי, לְאַחַר שֶׁיָּמוּת בַּעֲלֵךְ אוֹ לְאַחַר
>   שֶׁתָּמוּת אֲחוֹתֵךְ, לְאַחַר שֶׁיַּחֲלֹץ לָךְ יְבָמֵךְ, אֵינָהּ
>   מְקֻדֶּשֶׁת. וְכֵן הָאוֹמֵר לַחֲבֵרוֹ, אִם יָלְדָה אִשְׁתְּךָ נְקֵבָה
>   הֲרֵי הִיא מְקֻדֶּשֶׁת לִי, אֵינָהּ מְקֻדֶּשֶׁת. אִם הָיְתָה אֵשֶׁת
>   חֲבֵרוֹ מְעֻבֶּרֶת וְהֻכַּר עֻבָּרָהּ, דְּבָרָיו קַיָּמִין, וְאִם
>   יָלְדָה נְקֵבָה, מְקֻדֶּשֶׁת:
>
> [With regard to] one who betroths a woman, and [later] says, "I had
>   thought that she was a Kohenet [daughter of a Kohen] and behold she is
>   a Levite;" "A Levite, and behold she is a Kohenet;" "Poor, and behold
>   she is rich;" "Rich, and behold she is poor;" [in all these cases] she
>   is betrothed, because she did not deceive him. **[With regard to] one
>   who says to a woman, "You are hereby betrothed to me after I convert;"
>   "After you convert;" "After I am freed;" "After you are freed;" "After
>   your husband dies;" "After your sister dies;" "After your yavam
>   performs chalitzah [the ceremony performed to release a widow of a
>   childless man from the obligation of levirate marriage];" [in all
>   these cases] she is not betrothed**. Similarly, [with regard to] one who
>   says to his fellow, "If your wife gives birth to a female, [the child]
>   is hereby betrothed to me," she is not betrothed. If his fellow's wife
>   was visibly pregnant, his words are valid; and if she gives birth to a
>   female, she is betrothed.

Comment: Interesting, but the question was whether a woman owned a slave. I don't see how this answers it.

Comment: To me this shows what a Jewish woman would halachically do, before her man-slave can become her husband. Now whether this was done in the Tanach we would need a different source.

Comment: @ninamag it does not say anything about who the owner of the slave is, it seems it is also reffuring to when she was not the owner

Comment: @hazoriz Does not Yevamoth 67a clearly examples a woman who inherits and, therefore, owns male slaves?

Comment: @ninamag I see that she owns male slaves but nothing about inheritance in that Source https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.67a.4

Comment: @hazoriz מתני׳ בת ישראל שניסת לכהן ומת והניחה מעוברת לא יאכלו עבדיה בתרומה מפני חלקו של עובר שהעובר פוסל ואינו מאכיל דברי ר' יוסי (Yevamot 67a), does this passage not suggest that the reason she owns the slaves is because she inherited them from and upon the death of her husband?

Comment: @ninamag upon the death of her husband yes, inherited them no, it is quite possible she was given the slaves as dowry from her father, but her husband has the right to use her property until he dyes or divorces her (a wife never inherits her husband, unless she was his cousin (or other relative) and no other relatives are alive)

Comment: @hazoriz if her father gave her male slaves, is not that also the same way to say, she inherited males slaves from her father?

Comment: @ninamag the case can be her husband dyes her father is still alive now she owns the slaves (if you can inherit from a living person then yes)

Comment: @hazoriz Though it is unlikely that a Jew/Jewess would ask for his/her family inheritance while the father is still alive, surely many a father upon learning of his impending demise have actually dispensed the inheritance to his child while still alive, no? (This, in part, is practiced when an old king is still alive, he sometimes hands-over already the heritable monarchy to his child.)

Comment: @ninamag I think technically it is considered a gift not inheritence