# What should a woman do if she owns male slaves

Tags: halacha, slave-serve-eved-avadim

It seems a woman is forbidden to acquire male slaves

Rambam [Avodim 1.2](http://www.chabad.org/1363800/) and [Shulchan Aruch 267.19](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.267.19)

What should/must she do if she does?
For example her property (Nichsai Milug and Tzon Barzel) she gets back after divorce or death of husband.
Or if she inherited them.

Sources please

Comment: Isn't is obvious that she should get rid of them (sell them or let them free)? Why would you think that isn't the case that you need to ask?

Comment: Source please (is it not forbbiden to let a slave free unless it is for a Mitzvah?) She can get married (and they will become/stay nichsai tzon barzel , (and might be shevach Bais oviha)), is there not an idea that Hatorah haza al manmona Shel Yesroel

Comment: @DoubleAA if she must get rid of them how much time does she have to do it?

Comment: @DoubleAA see comments here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84798/5120 in mishna yevamot 67 https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.67a.4 it seems she owns male slaves and is not getting rid of them